# How to connect spring gcp PubSubTemplate to local instance?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-gcp

i'm using spring boot starter `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub` and `PubSubTemplate`. it works perfectly with actual GCP but now i want to use it for my tests with local Google PubSub emulator. how can i provide my custom url, port and no credentials?

or i have to revert back to using plain google sdk as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51290024/spring-boot-cloud-gcp-cannot-connect-to-local-google-pubsub-emulator)

---

**EDIT**:

i have only one bean in my app:

```
@Service
class TestLocalPubsub(pubSubTemplate: PubSubTemplate)
```

and

application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.emulator-host=localhost:8085
```

and when i run the app i got:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
>       at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:132) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.12.0.jar:na]
>   ...

but of course the link says about gcloud sdk, not pubsubtemplate

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? I

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54990147/1475386) answer, might be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot cloud GCP cannot connect to local Google PubSub emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51290024/spring-boot-cloud-gcp-cannot-connect-to-local-google-pubsub-emulator)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the post you linked, there are couple ways to get spring to connect to emulator:

- Set an environment variable `SPRING_CLOUD_GCP_PUBSUB_EMULATORHOST=locahost:8085` (if using the default emulator port
- Or set `spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.emulator-host=localhost:8085` in your Spring application properties

For tests, you can use the second method by creating an application.properties in test/main/resources and setting `spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.emulator-host=localhost:8085`. You shouldn't need to override any custom credentials.

In order for your tests to work with emulator, you need to create your topics and subscriptions in the emulator ahead of time. The GCP docs show how to do this manually by installing Python Google Cloud Client library: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator. Otherwise your tests need to create them using the SDK.

Here is a complete example of using Spring with pubsub emulator and creating the topic/subscription using Java SDK: https://github.com/nhartner/pubsub-emulator-demo

Comment: Please check out my example project to see how to use emulator in a test: https://github.com/nhartner/pubsub-emulator-demo